# UITapGestureRecognizer in UITableView - first cell is ignored by tap gesture

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to make a certain area of my cell respond to a tap gesture. For that, I added a UIView called "touchViewProfile" in my cell. This code has been added as is in cellForRowAtIndexPath :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

    SimpleTableCell *cell = (SimpleTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:1];
    }

     // Tag Gesture Recognizer for Profile
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapProfile = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                              initWithTarget:self
                                              action:@selector(showProfile)];
        tapProfile.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        tapProfile.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
        cell.touchViewProfile.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        [cell.touchViewProfile addGestureRecognizer:tapProfile];

    return cell;
}
```

It works for every cell except the first one. Did I forget something? I declared "UIGestureRecognizerDelegate" in my .h

EDIT: "touchViewProfile" is a UIView I created with Interface Builder in SimpleTableCell.xib. It's a property, synthesized in .m

Comment: If you show us how you set up the cells internally as well `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method it might help us to help.

Comment: I commented everything else to reduce the possibility of errors.

Comment: I appreciate you willingness to remove cruft, but the tap gesture-recognizer logic seems sound. It seems likely that it is some minor detail (like when exactly you are doing what) that might cause your problem. Without a larger context it is very hard to dig in...

Comment: can you show code where you create the cell?

Comment: Are you using `registerNib: forCellReuseIdentifier:` - if your cell is a xib-file, that is (?), then you can skip the if(cell == nil). It seems somewhat flakey that you're referring to a particular index inside the nib...

Comment: Yes it's a .xib file. I don't see the problem with this way, it has always worked in my other apps.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a problem, but you're basically referring to a magic index-number in and array of interface-elements. I'd definitely insist the tableView method I mentioned is a more robust solution. That being said, I'm not positive that's your problem though. Have you inspected that the cell is of the correct class after the cell = [nib objectAtIndex:1] is executed?

Comment: Yes, because I have other properties (UIImageView, UILabels, etc) connected the exact same way as the "touchViewProfile" UIView. I'm setting their value at the same place, in CellForRowAtIndexPath (but I commented it to explicitly test the tap gesture). So the connection to my custom cell is definitely not the issue here. Autolayout maybe? I added a tap gesture to the image in my cell, and it only detects the tap on the lower-right half of the image for the first cell. Tap on the first top half isn't detected. Again, this is only for the first cell, the other behave fine.

Comment: @nickfalk is correct. `registerNib: forCellReuseIdentifier:` has been the correct way to initialize cells in a table view since iOS 5.

Comment: Additionally, your `addGestureRecognizer` logic is flawed. Table view cells are reused as you scroll, so you are adding multiple gesture recognizers to the same cell. You should add the gesture recognizer in one of the initialization methods of `SimpleTableCell`, then send messages back to your table view owner in the form of delegate callbacks.

Comment: Good catch by daltonclaybrook. Also, are you positive the first cell's touchViewProfile is alive when setting the gesture recognizer to it?

Comment: @nickfalk How to verify is it's "alive" ? I am setting properties and they are correctly showing up on the UI, even on the first cell.

Comment: @daltonclaybrook I added "[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"SimpleTableCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]
         forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MyCustomCell"];" to viewDidLoad and replaced the cell init code in CellForRow with "SimpleTableCell *cell = (SimpleTableCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCustomCell"];", but I get an Assertion failure at the line in CellForRow.

Comment: @anthoprotic You need to use `- (id)dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have ceell index value first so we need to implement UIGesture Delegate

```
-(void)showProfile:(UIGestureRecognization *)recognize{
  if(recognize.state==UIGestureRecognizeStateEnded){
     CGPoint touched=[recognize locationInVie:self.tableView];
     NSIndexPath *touchIndex=[self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoin:touched];
     SimpleTableViewCell *touchedCell=[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:touchedIndex];
     //your code
   }
}
```